Safety of using non-primitive objects in Unity ECS (DOTS)
I'm making ECS project rn, an some of my components have string variables in it. Unity complains that strings are not primitive and marks this as red flag in console. Should I worry about and replace strings with something primitive/write some script that turns string values in primitives, or it is not a very dangerous problem?
Using Entities 0.51.1-preview.21 - August 02, 2022
Unity 2021.3.28f1 Personal Windows
Don't tried anything

The amazon-ecs tag is for Amazon Web Services Elastic Container Service. It is unrelated to Unity ECS.

I would guess this has to do with types being blittable. I know nothing about Unity ECS, but if it gives warnings I would try to find alternatives. But it probably depend on what the strings are used for.
